# Undefined symbol on xcode with custom library for ios (definition of the symbol is there)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I know there are other questions with that same title, but none of them have the same problem than me.

I have two projects. One of them builds a library, the other one builds an app that uses that library.

When I build the library it's all ok. It creates a .a file which contains the library. When I try to build the second project, I get the following message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback", referenced from:
      _register_spatialite_sql_functions in liblibspatialite.a(spatialite.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thats bad. At first I did not know what it was talking about, but after some research, found that the library may have not be built for armv7, so I used the lipo command to check the architecture:

```
lipo -info liblibspatialite.a
```

This produces the following output.

```
Non-fat file: liblibspatialite.a is architecture: armv7
```

Ok so the architecture is right. Then what? Maybe check for the symbols of the .o files that will conform the library. For that I used the nm command:

```
nm spatialite.o | grep SPLite3_rt
```

Which produces the following output:

```
U _SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback
```

I checked the manpage for nm and saw that the U before the symbol means it's undefined. So it seems that's it. The symbol appears as undefined. I have another version of the project in another workspace. I've checked, and it produces a working library. The nm command returns the following on that other version:

```
0000e5f6 T _SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback
0018c668 S _SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback.eh
```

So, with this library it's working and it's fine. I've tried to find differences in the build options of both projects but they look the same to me.
I can build with the first version of the library if I include the source files of the library in the compiler section of the properties of the project. (Select target -> Build phases -> Compile sources), but I think that's not the point of using a library.

So, I'd like to know what can I do so that the _SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback gets included in the library.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Some more info. In spatialite.c, there is the following code:

```
#define sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback

SQLITE_API int sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback(
sqlite3 *db,
  const char *zGeom,
  int (*xGeom)(sqlite3_rtree_geometry *, int nCoord, double *aCoord, int *pRes),
  void *pContext
);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Code for the method:

```
/*
** Register a new geometry function for use with the r-tree MATCH operator.
*/

SQLITE_API int sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback(
  sqlite3 *db,
  const char *zGeom,
  int (*xGeom)(sqlite3_rtree_geometry *, int, double *, int *),
  void *pContext
){
  RtreeGeomCallback *pGeomCtx;      /* Context object for new user-function */

  /* Allocate and populate the context object. */
  pGeomCtx = (RtreeGeomCallback *)sqlite3_malloc(sizeof(RtreeGeomCallback));
  if( !pGeomCtx ) return SQLITE_NOMEM;
  pGeomCtx->xGeom = xGeom;
  pGeomCtx->pContext = pContext;

  /* Create the new user-function. Register a destructor function to delete
  ** the context object when it is no longer required.  */
  return sqlite3_create_function_v2(db, zGeom, -1, SQLITE_ANY, 
      (void *)pGeomCtx, geomCallback, 0, 0, doSqlite3Free
  );
}
```

Comment: The code in spatialite.c is a declaration. Where is the definition?

Comment: @JefferyThomas The code is in the file sqlite3.c . I posted it beneath EDIT 2.

Comment: Use nm to see if `_sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback` is defined in the library. If so, then `#define sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback` is missing from sqlite3.c

Comment: @JefferyThomas _sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback does not appear on the list if I use nm on liblibspatialite.a; What does show is          U _SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback; Anyway, I checked sqlite3.c and there it is #define sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback SPLite3_rtree_geometry_callback

Comment: Not very good. The only things left are the code is conditionally excluded and `SQLITE_API` is defined differently in the two files. Look for #if... before `SQLITE_API int sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback(` that could be excluding that function. Make sure that `SQLITE_API` has the same definition for both files.

Comment: @JefferyThomas SQLITE_API is just defined as: ifnot defined, define SQLITE_API. SQLITE_API int sqlite3_rtree_geometry_callback is not inside any conditional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This seems weird but it looks like I finally fixed it. Everything is correctly defined, so why it is not working I don't know.

I was using the xcode target preferences to define the preprocessor macros. Instead of that, I changed the SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE to the .pch file, and after that the build contains the missing symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `spacialite.c` is added to the library's target.

Comment: Yes it's added. In fact the library is just composed by two large files. spatialite.c and sqlite3.c

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE in preproccessor macro